# Displaying html table in Jade? Unexpected Text Error

Tags: html, pug

I'm trying to display a basic html table in a jade template however I'm getting this error:

```
Error: c:\2406Node\myapp\views\table.jade:7
   5|       table, th, td {
   6|       border: 1px solid black;
 > 7|       }
   8|   body
   9|     table(style="width:100%")
   10|       tr

unexpected text }
 b
   at Object.Lexer.fail (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:872:11)
   at Object.Lexer.next (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:931:15)
   at Object.Lexer.lookahead (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:113:46)
   at Parser.lookahead (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:102:23)
   at Parser.peek (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:79:17)
   at Parser.tag (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:810:30)
   at Parser.parseTag (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:737:17)
   at Parser.parseExpr (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:211:21)
   at Parser.tag (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:797:29)
   at Parser.parseTag (c:\2406Node\myapp\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:737:17)
```

Here is my jade file containing the table:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    style
      table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      }
  body
    table(style="width:100%")
      tr
        th
        th TA
        th Start Date
        th Deadline
        th Completion Date
        th Comment
      tr
        th A1
        th Chris
        td
        td
        td
        td
      tr
        th
        th Lucas
        td
        td
        td
        td
      tr
        th
        th Muhammad
        td
        td
        td
        td
      tr
        th
        th Lee
        td
        td
        td
        td
```

and here is the html I'm converting to jade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>TA</th>     
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>Deadline</th>
    <th>Completion Date</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>A1</th>
    <th>Chris</th>      
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Lucas</th>      
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Muhammad</th>       
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Lee</th>        
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Just need to know what I'm doing wrong and if jade requires a change to my current code in order to properly display the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the closing brace for the styles up onto the previous line:

```
    style
      table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;}
```

Comment: It fixed the error and the text is displaying properly now thank you! However, the table or borders aren't displaying, I can only see the text. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Got it to work, had to add a . after style to stop it from parsing